# O gera o erro Can't set headers after they are sent,está executando 2 vezes

Tags: node.js, express.js

Ele está executando o conteudo o `validator` 2 vezes, sou novo com *Node.js* e não sei o que está acontecendo.

Quando o validator retorna um erro á *API* para, quando não tenho retorno de um erro á api funciona normal.

```
function alterar(req,res){

    validator.validaValores(req.body,(err,data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }else{
            console.log("Teste")
            repository.alterar(req.body, (err,data) => {
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).json(err)
                }else{
                    res.status(200).json({mesage: 'Alterado com sucesso!'})
                }    
            })
        }      
    })
}
```

Este é o erro, os dois `console.log()` que dou no código aparecem ali, porém deveria aparecer apenas aquele com o mensagem de erro.

{ erro: 'Dados inválidos!' }

Teste
    _http_outgoing.js:489
        throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
        ^

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at repository.alterar (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/src/core/valores/teste/testeController.js:39:37)
    at sql.request.input.input.input.input.input.execute (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/src/core/valores/teste/testeRepository.js:48:17)
    at /home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/node_modules/mssql/lib/main.js:1632:20
    at Request.userCallback (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:1137:61)
    at Request.callback (/home/thiago/projeto/projeto/projeto_api/node_modules/tedious/lib/request.js:39:27)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Não faz sentido ele entrar nos dois na mesma rodagem, talvez esteja rodando mais de uma vez, veja isso. E não precisa do `return` em caso de erro, pode removê-lo. E o erro pode estar sendo exibido, pois quando você faz `.json(err)`, o conteúdo deve ser um json válido, talvez seja somente uma string, ou código, etc.

Comment: Obrigado @LucasCosta eu fiz o teste e ele está executando 2 vezes,vou tentar fazer com que ele tenha uma unica execução agora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que estava sendo executado duas vezes a função do meu `validator` então solucionei da seguinte forma:

```
function alterar(req,res){
try{
    validator.validaValores(req.body,(err) => {
        if(err){
            throw err
        }else{
            repository.alterar(req.body, (err,data) => {
                if(err){
                    throw err
                }else{
                    res.status(200).json({mesage:'Alterado com sucesso!'})    
                }    
            })
        }      
    })
}catch(err){
    return res.status(500).json(err)
}
```

}

Troquei os `return` por `throw` usando `try catch` para capturar o erro e assim finalizar a `function alterar` deixando apenas dois retornos.